# What are android sdk platforms? which package details do i need for certain api level?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I installed android studio & I checked SDK manager that only API level 25 & 24 is installed. I want to install other API levels like API 23 for Marshmallow & API 22 for Lollipop. 
  But before installing there are package details option. When i checked it there was many option. 
   So I want to know which options shall I choose (or necessary) to install certain API. I want to create app for mobile device only>SDK Manager Image for API 23

[image]

As the image shows API level 23 which I want to install. So please tell me which option shall I choose? Because their are many options new which are neither available for API level 24 nor for API 25. 
  The only thing I know that Android TV & Android wear should not be checked. what about the other options please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meed is Android SDK Platform 23, maybe you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your `targetSdkVersion` to `23` in `app/build.gradle` and `Android Studio` will ask you to sync and download needed tools.